# Play framework future does not getting faster

Tags: mysql, multithreading, scala, playframework

I am new scala and play framework 2.6. I am using Futures for MYSQL database insert and select operations for 30000 records. I tried and tested my project with number of 2,4,8 and 16 future. Elapsed time getting bigger or same when i increase futures count. I am using play's default excecution context and Play's default database configurations. I think it should be about configuration. But i could not find problem. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: maybe you need to configure mysql pool https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsJDBC
or to tune default thread pool in play https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools

Answer (score 0):

Reactive implementation (on futures) make your app faster only on heavy loads. To achieve boost You need to implement everything correctly, tune paramaters (thread pools, memory limits, db connection limits etc) and be sure there are no external blockers like database.

At the begging please check database performance. Usually it is slowest part of application. Maybe You can switch to NoSQL database like MongoDB? It has excellent support in play framework (play-reactivemongo)